# A property of countable dense subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non discrete topological space and let $D$ be a countably infinite dense subset. Is it true that $D$ less a finite subset is still dense? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, non-discrete is not enough. A space $X$ can have isolated points, i.e. $x \in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is open. These always have to be in any dense set $D$ (as $D$ has to intersect the non-empty open set $\{x\}$). So we want $X$ to be "dense in itself", or $X$ has no isolated points.

Second, we need $T_1$-ness of $X$ (which is pretty mild), which is equivalent to all finite sets being closed. If $D$ is dense and $X$ is $T_1$ without isolated points, then no finite non-empty subset $F$ can be open (check this) and then, if $O$ is open and non-empty, so is $O \setminus F$, and so $D$ must also intersect $O \setminus F$, which is equivalent to $O$ intersecting $D \setminus F$, so the latter set is dense whenever $D$ is. If $X$ is not $T_1$ this might fail, and finite sets could be dense (and not omitted). E.g. take the natural numbers and let $O$ be open iff it is empty or it contains both $0$ and $1$. Then $\{0,1\}$ is dense and there are no isolated points.

So the answer is yes: for spaces without isolated points, and that are also $T_1$, and both conditions are necessary.

Comment: sorry but why $D\setminus F$ intersects every open of $X$ ? You said that $D$ intersects $X\setminus F$. It seems different to me. thank you

Comment: @Richard I edited it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $X$ is the union of the real line and any finite subset $F$  open sets of $X$ are the union of open subsets of $R$ and subsets of $F$. Take  $D=$  $Q+F$, where $Q$ are the rational numbers, $Q$ is not dense in $X$.

Comment: I think he meant union instead of $+$.